# touchpad-indicator doesn't disable touchpad

Tags: touchpad

I've installed the util from PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

In the software preferences I've selected "Disable touchpad on typing" and "Disable touchpad when mouse plugged"

Both don't work.

```
root@workbee:/home/alex# xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SEM USB Keyboard                          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3336-001                      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse                       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SEM USB Keyboard                          id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ EasyCamera: EasyCamera                    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Lenovo IdeaPad 320-15IKB

**UPDATE**

I've remembered an important detail.

Sometimes ago (a week or two) I installed the same (I think) touchpad indicator on some other system. Unfortunately, I don't remember how I installed it, and what system exactly was, but I remember that it had a very useful option in its settings, something like "Input Source" or "Input Method". It was a dropdown menu with 3 options. By switching between options I was able to make Touchpad Indicator able to manage touchpad status. I want to have that settings again.

Comment: I would run it by the author of the software [atareao-team](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao)

Comment: What do you mean? To log a bug there?

Comment: I used Touchpad-indicator with some previous releases of Lubuntu, but I have problems with some of the newer versions. Maybe some features you want have disappeared in the version of Touchpad-indicator for Ubuntu 16.04. I agree with @stumblebee, that you should ask the developer for help directly (via a bug report or more directly, if you can establish a dialogue).

Comment: What does `uname -r` report for kernel version?

Comment: `4.13.0-26-generic`

Answer (score 0):

### Try the following `synclient` commands,

From `man synaptics`

> ```
>    Option "TouchpadOff" "integer"
>           Switch off the touchpad.  Valid values are:
>
>           0   Touchpad is enabled
>           1   Touchpad is switched off (physical clicks still work)
>           2   Only tapping and scrolling is switched off
>           When  the  touchpad  is  switched off, button events caused by a
>           physical button press are still interpreted. On a ClickPad, this
>           includes  software-emulated  middle and right buttons as defined
>           by the SoftButtonAreas setting.
>
>    Property: "Synaptics Off"
> ```

Try the following commands to turn the touchpad on and off

```
synclient touchpadoff=0
synclient touchpadoff=1
```

They work for me for example in Lubuntu and Xubuntu. If they work for you, create aliases for them to make things convenient.

There is a GUI alternative in standard Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

- Click on the icon with a cog wheel and a wrench
- Select Mouse and Touchpad
- Click on the switch at the right side of the window to toggle <kbd>on/off</kbd>.